# Model binding validation errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

In my custom model validation, I have the following:

```
 public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext){
        var repository = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(IContactRepository));
        IContactRepository repo = repository as IContactRepository;
        USRContact c = repo.GetContactByID(Convert.ToInt64(bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("ContactID").AttemptedValue));
        c.FormalName = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("FormalName").AttemptedValue;

        if (!repo.IsValidFormalName(c.ContactID, c.FormalName))
        {
            var result = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError("FormalName", Resources.ErrorMsgs.FormalNameNotUnique);

            return bindingContext.Model;
        }

        c.PreferredName = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("PreferredName").AttemptedValue;
        c.Alias = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("Alias").AttemptedValue;
        c.Pseudonym = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("Pseudonym").AttemptedValue;
        c.GenderID = Convert.ToInt32(bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("GenderID").AttemptedValue);
        c.NationalityID = Convert.ToInt32(bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("NationalityID").AttemptedValue);
        c.ModifiedByID = Utilities.SessionUtil.Current.UserID;
        c.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
```

}

My controller calls this model binder by doing the following:

```
public ActionResult Update([ModelBinder(typeof(ModelBinder.ContactModelBinder))] USR.USRContact contact)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            repository.Update();
            return View("~/Views/Shared/Contacts/ShowContactInfo.cshtml", repository.GetContactByID(contact.ContactID));
        }
}
```

}

My viewmodel contains the data annotations to say that formal name is required and that alias needs to be less than 60 characters. How do I display the errors if the model binder transformed it to the persistent data model(USRContact) and my view is expecting the viewmodel?

Is there any way to make sure that on validation errors on the view model, the controller doesn't transform to persistent data model? Even if we do check for all the model errors in the data object and find the validation errors, how do we send the user back to the view they were just in with the errors next to the textboxes that they had the error in.

Thanks for the help!
Safris

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you may be facing is that once you push those values into the other object through the custom binder they are no longer the same as they were on the page.

A property called "PropertyValue" with an Html.ValidationFor(x=>x.PropertyValue) is going to look in the ModelState error collection for items with PropertyValue.

Once you have pushed those into Contact now the value is Contact.PropertyValue.  If you validated it then it will be added to the ModelState as "Contact.PropertyValue"  This will only be picked up by Html.ValidationFor(x=>x.Contact.PropertyValue)

The easiest solution is to make sure that your input and output's follow the same structure.  If you can render the items as Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Contact.SomeProperty) then things will be fine.